# Manually writing code for a Simple CNN using Backpropagation?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, convolution

Are there any resources online that offer examples of how to write a CNN from scratch?

Specifically, I am looking to understand the inner-workings of the backpropagation steps within a 1-D or 2-D CNN.  I can find the equations for backpropagation online, but I am having trouble translating that into code within a CNN.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the popular libraries have rather large amount of code, it can take days to figure out what's happening indeed.

There's a nice illustration with some sample code on [Stanford's cs231 course](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#conv). If you're comfortable with matlab, there's a simple library [DeepLearnToolbox](https://github.com/rasmusbergpalm/DeepLearnToolbox.git) you might want to look at. It actually hasn't been updated for years, so it only contains the basic building blocks and algorithms, which IMO makes it a good starting point for beginners. Cheers.